# warning: control may reach end of non-void function problem

Tags: c++

Well, i made RGB To Hex Conversion. My programm in online compiler works pretty well, but on codewars it has a problem "control may reach end of non-void function". What should i do? Should I remove `for` loop?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int checkForNumber(int input) {
    if (input > 255) return 255;
    if (input < 0) return 0;
    else return input;
}
string check(int input) {
    if (input < 10) return to_string(input);

    switch (input)
    {
    case 10:
        return "A";
        break;
    case 11:
        return "B";
        break;
    case 12:
        return "C";
        break;
    case 13:
        return "D";
        break;
    case 14:
        return "E";
        break;
    case 15:
        return "F";
        break;
    }
}
**string YES(int input) {
    string m;
    char temp;
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        m += check(input % 16);
        input /= 16;**
//problem is somewhere here
    }
    temp = m[0];
    m[0] = m[1];
    m[1] = temp;
    return m;
}
int main()
{
    string output;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int r = 148 , g = 0, b = 211;
    r = checkForNumber(r);
    g = checkForNumber(g);
    b = checkForNumber(b);
    
   output += YES(r) + YES(g) + YES(b);
   cout << output;
    
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in `YES`, but with `check`. Compiler warns you that you return nothing if `input` is greater than 15.

Comment: An unrelated note: None of those `break`s  has purpose.since you `return` on the line above them.

Comment: Before the end of check, put in `throw std::logic_error("should never happen");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `check(int input)` function -- consider what happens if the value of the `input` argument is not in the range [10, 15].  I suggest putting in a `default:` case that returns something appropriate at the bottom of your `switch` block.

Comment: Well, the case where `input < 10` is taken care of, but yes, `input > 15` is the problem.

Comment: Hm, I'll try. Thank you

Comment: @LEXALEPEX And when you do, make sure that you return the same appropriate value `if(input < 0)`